# pass value from embeded viewcontroller to the Homecontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have the UITextField in the embedded viewcontroller and the button in the main homecontroller. i want to pass the values from the input field to the home controller so that i can check for null values on button click.

the value of UserId and Password should be passed to the HomeController

following is my code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class HomeController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak
    var loginContainerShadow: UIView!@IBOutlet weak
    var login: UIButton!

        @IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {
            let myObj: ViewController = self.children.last as!ViewController;
            let userid: UITextField = myObj.UserId!as UITextField;
            print(userid)
        }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loginContainerShadow.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        loginContainerShadow.layer.shadowColor = (UIColor(red: 0 / 255.0, green: 0 / 138.0, blue: 0 / 140.0, alpha: 7).cgColor)
        loginContainerShadow.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.75)
        loginContainerShadow.layer.shadowRadius = 1
        loginContainerShadow.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.45
        login.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor(red: 172.0 / 255.0, green: 146.0 / 255, blue: 236.0 / 255.0, alpha: 100), colorTwo: UIColor(red: 109.0 / 255.0, green: 71.0 / 255, blue: 204.0 / 255, alpha: 100))
        login.layer.cornerRadius = 25

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set < UITouch > , with event: UIEvent ? ) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}


import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var checked = "no";


    @IBOutlet
    var loginContainerShadow: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak
    var UserId: UITextField!{
        didSet {
            UserId.setBottomBorder()
            UserId.delegate = self
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak
    var Password: UITextField!{
        didSet {
            Password.setBottomBorder()
            Password.delegate = self
        }
    }


    @IBOutlet
    var UserIdValidate: UIImageView!@IBOutlet
    var PasswordValidate: UIImageView!

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set < UITouch > , with event: UIEvent ? ) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func UserIdChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        if UserId.text == "" {
            UserId.setBottomBorder()
        } else {
            UserId.setPurpleBottomBorder()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func PasswordChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        if Password.text == "" {
            Password.setBottomBorder()
        } else {
            Password.setPurpleBottomBorder()
        }
    }


    @IBOutlet weak
    var RememberMe: UIButton!
    @IBAction func RemenberMe(_ sender: Any) {
        if (checked == "no") {
            RememberMe.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_button_unchecked"),
                for: UIControl.State.normal)
            checked = "yes"
        } else if (checked == "yes") {
            RememberMe.setImage(UIImage(named: "proper"),
                for: UIControl.State.normal)
            checked = "no"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create custom delegates for passing values

Comment: can you tell me how? im new to swift

Comment: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/pass-data-with-delegation-in-swift-86f6bc5d0894 this is a tutorial refer this will help